# Include a form for a related object in a modelform in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two models like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    house = models.ForeignKey('House')

class House(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField()
```

Is there some way to create a model form for `Person` and have it include inline the form to edit the related `House` object as well?  From what I understand of the inline formsets stuff, I would only use that if I have a form editing a `House` and I want to display forms for all the related `Person`s.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Just stick the HouseForm into the PersonForm, evaluate it as part of the clean() process, and save it as part of the save() process. Works in a modelformset too.

```
class HouseForm(forms.modelForm):
    """ Edit a house """
    class Meta:
        model = House
        exclude = ()

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Edit a person and her house """
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['house'].required = False
        data = kwargs.get('data')
        # 'prefix' parameter required if in a modelFormset
        self.house_form = HouseForm(instance=self.instance and self.instance.house, 
                                    prefix=self.prefix, data=data)

    def clean(self):
        if not self.house_form.is_valid():
            raise forms.ValidationError("House not valid")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(PersonForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        obj.house = self.house_form.save()
        obj.save()
```

Then in your markup:

```
<form ...>
    {{ person_form }}
    {{ person_form.house_form }}
</form>
```

Comment: You should also override the `has_changed()` function. To look like this:
`def has_changed(self): return (super(PersonForm, self).has_changed() or self.house_form.has_changed())` Because without that your form might not get saved [Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L778)

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the related House object through the Person. As such, I would use the house object as the instance for a Modelform.

```
HouseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = House
```

Say you have a Person object of Paul with a related House.

```
house_form = HouseForm(instance=Paul.house)
```

Is this what you were getting at?

Comment: Not exactly.  What I want to do is create a PersonForm, but have it include almost a subform for HouseForm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it is the best way to solve it, but I would do something like this:

Define a `ModelForm` from each model:

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

class HouseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = House
```

Define a template like this one, outputting both forms:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        {{ form1 }}
        {{ form2 }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

A view to create the form to edit the information from both models.

```
def edit(request):
    # You could grab the id from the request that calls the edit form
    p = models.Person.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get('id'))
    h = models.House.objects.get(pk=p.house.id)
    return render_to_response('template.html',
        RequestContext(request, 
            {'form1': PersonForm(instance=p), 'form2': HouseForm(instance=h)}
        )
    )
```

And so on.

Comment: I will probably end up doing something like this, I just felt like there might be a more Django Way of doing things.